# How to add non-movable UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

How do I insert non-movable `UITableViewCell` just like they appear underneath Apple's Timer in the Clock App via Storyboard?

Is there perhaps a way to add static `UITableViewCell` to a basic `UIViewController` without adding an `UITableView`?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you mean _"non-movable"_? can you be more specific, please?

Comment: Default TableViewCells in a TableView scroll as the user tries to scroll through the tableView. But in the Clock App on the iPhone there is a cell underneath the Timer which does not scroll then. It is kind of "fixed"

Comment: you may want to set the `scrollEnabled` to `FALSE` in a `UITableView`...? or the `bounces` to `FALSE`? I'm not sure what the issue is here... :(

Comment: Yes, thank you! I just didn't find that option. Now I got it

Comment: everything is in black and white in the `UITableView` Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html ...

Answer (score 0):

No, you definitely can't have a `UITableViewCell` without a table view. And I don't see any problem to create a fake `UITableView` with `userInteractionEnabled = NO` with cells that have a `@" "` for `cell.textLabel.text`. But I'd go for a `UIImageView` here.

Answer (score 0):

To implement somethign like the alarn functionality

- In your view controller, if you have a tableview then make it cover only half of the screen.

  - Add a UIView and then drag and drop 2 buttons. One for pause and one for Cancel and one for resume.
  - In your code, add 2 IBAction functions. Then connect these buttons to these functions with "Touch up inside"

You can setting images for these buttons and background for the view to make it look like you want it to.

Hth